# What are the best Image transcoding libraries/Solutions available?

Tags: .net, image-processing

My project requires some image transcoding functionality, i.e converting images into various formats.  My requirements are:

- Preferably scalable, for performance reasons.
- Compatible with Microsoft .NET
- Can be either paid software, or FOSS.

Can anyone suggest some good libraries they have come across. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used [LeadTools](http://www.leadtools.com/sdk/imaging-pro.htm) before now, and it worked fine. It was a little bit fiddly to use, but it definitely got the job done. There are various editions available (all commercial AFAIK). I'm not sure what you mean about being a scalable solution - did you have any specific feature in mind?

Answer (score 1):

The [Windows Imaging Component](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Imaging_Component) via WPF is decent, and if you are doing fairly routine transcoding of popular formats, should work well. However, I've noticed [some problems](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowswic/thread/c617b5a1-de2d-49af-84c8-a227ba6d10d2/) when using some of the more esoteric parts of the TIFF image format.

Answer (score 0):

Most of what you need should be doable inside the .Net framework. Have a look at [Graphics.DrawIcon()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d6s01xzx.aspx)